# How is information encoded in the Cosmological Horizon?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

It is my understanding, according to the "Holographic Universe Theory", that multi-dimensional volume somehow emerges from a two-dimensional surface called the "Cosmological Horizon". And all three-dimensional reality is extruded from encoded information in this horizon. Is this horizon a purely mathamatical construct, or is it a real, perhaps light-like boundary? If information is pre-encoded on this surface, who or what does the encoding?

Comment: So far, it is conjecture but has some credibility to it. There is not much of a mathematical construct, depending on how you define mathematical. The surface is something you need to be careful with - In case of rigourous GR proof's as in the case of the posititve mass theorem or the Cauchy problem, the surface is a null hypersurface. Is the information pre-encoded? No. Holographic duality is non-local in this sense. How is the information encoded? This is very much an open problem.

Comment: Part of the problem is the definition of "information", by which physicists really mean "entropy". In an information theoretical sense entropy is the opposite of information, it's how much information would be needed to reconstruct the entire state. Does the cosmological horizon (which keeps shrinking (!) by the way) contain all the information about the future? Sure, yes, if you go to the end of time and all the photons that have ever been generated in the bulk have been lost to there, yes, but what are you doing with such an abstract construct. It's like saying "God has Alzheimer's".

Comment: What cosmological horizon are we talking about? Particle horizon? Hubble Radius? Future light cone? Present event horizon? Those have all different radii and a different evolution in time...

Answer (score 0):

The cosmological horizon is out at a distance of about 12 billion light years, which is about $1.2\times 10^{26}$m. This is then an area of $1.8\times 10^{53}m^2$. I will use Bekenstein's bound to estimate the entropy of the universe,
$$
S = k\frac{A}{4\ell_p^2} = 1.38\times 10^{-23}j/K\frac{1.8\times 10^{53}m^2}{2.5\times 10^{-66}m^2} 
$$
$$
= 1.38\times 10^{-23}j/K\times 7.0\times 10^{127}m^2 =  1.0\times 10^{105}j/K
$$
How do I get the energy? It will not work to multiply by the CMB temperature, for that is not the horizon temperature.The temperature is 
$$
T = \frac{\hbar c}{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{\Lambda}{3}} \simeq 2.8\times 10^{-53}K, 
$$
where $\Lambda$ is the cosmological constant. I now multiply this by the entropy for $E = ST$ to get $E = 2.8\times 10^{48}kg$. The mass of a proton is $1.6\times 10^{-27}kg$, and I now divide this into the energy I obtain to get the number of protons which is $N = 1.8\times 10^{79}$ This is close to the actual estimate.

The particles and field in the volume contained in the space bounded by the cosmological horizon are equivalent to what we might assign to the holographic screen on the horizon.

Comment: But then, the horizon in an accelerating universe is getting smaller, so it's not $1.8\times 10^{79}$, but only $1$... until it's zero.

Comment: The event horizon will shrink (in comoving coordinates, in proper coordinates it will converge to a constant value), but the particle horizon will converge to a constant value (in comoving coordinates, in proper coordinates it will grow without bounds). So when talking about "the" cosmological horizon one needs to specify which out of the list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cosmological_horizons